# run script after xserver started

Tags: 14.04, scripts, xserver, xinput

I have a script which I would love to run after xserver has started. This file is located at `/home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh`.

How to I invoke this file after xserver has started?

Comment: After X starts or after you login?

Comment: @muru I wish for it to be run at the login screen, before I login. My script contains the command `xinput` which requires xserver to be running.

Comment: An upstart job with `start on started lightdm` might work.

Comment: @muru Ooo will try.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution might be to write an [upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/). Create a file in `/etc/init/myjob.conf`. That could look for example like this:

```
description     "My custom upstart job"

start on login-session-start

task

exec /path/to/script.sh
```

---

- The `description` defines a short explanation
- The `start on` statement describes, at which event the job is executed. We don't need a `stop on` statement here, I think.
- A `task` job is one which runs a short-running process, that is, a program which might still take a long time to run, but which has a definite lifetime and end state.
- `exec` is the main part of the job. Take care what environment variables your script needs to be successful. I assume, since your script must run after an X server has started, you need proper environment variables such as `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` and maybe also `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.
- If you have trouble, take a look at `/var/log/upstart/myjob.log` where all output of your job goes.

Comment: Script is not being executed on Ubuntu 16.04