# Trigger a program when X wakes up

Tags: automation, wakeup, randr

I want to perform a task when my computer awakens from suspend, and the task involves xcb-randr. I've tried putting a script into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`, but randr isn't available at the time that scripts in `system-sleep` get triggered. Is there an easy way to get my program to run *after* randr is available?

Comment: Do you wanna automatically reconfigure your display scheme at awake time? Does xcb-randr let an output to /tmp file? You could add a line `sleep nn` before xcb-randr command. _nn_ refers to how many seconds the command will be executed after.

Comment: @Redbob : yes, I want to apply `redshift` immediately. (I don't like redshift's server or f.lux's or any that I've seen, hence the manual change.) Surprisingly, even adding a 2-second `sleep` does not resolve the problem: redshift says `can't open display`, and `xrandr` says `Initialization of randr failed`

Comment: What release of Ubuntu do you run?

Comment: @Redbob : 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Try an upstart job instead of `system-sleep` script. For instance: https://askubuntu.com/a/704899/117018